# word choices related to Personal Protective Equipment

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Could you help me with this sentence? I don't know if I am writing it right, specially the the bold words :

> Personal Protective  Equipment ( PPE) is **specialized** clothing or equipment **worn** by **employees** for protection against health and **security** hazards. Personal protective equipment is designed to protect many parts of the body, i.e., eyes, head, face, hands, feet, and ears.

In particular:

- Should it be *special clothing*, or *specialized clothing*?
- Would it be better to day *worn by employees*, or *used by employees*?
- Which should it be: *security hazards* or *safety hazards*?

Comment: What about it bothers you?  Why do you think some of those words might be wrong?

Comment: (I might recommend replacing *security* with *safety*.)

Comment: I don't know if I should say : 

special clothing, rather than specialized clothing.  Worn or used. Security hazards or safety hazards

Comment: @user63598 - In the future, put such information in your question. Do not require us to **guess** why you are confused or seek help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Specialized* is definitely preferred over *special*.  Using *Special* here would mean 'unusual or unique in some way', whereas *specialized* means 'made with a particular, specific usage in mind'.  You could have "special glasses" that are special because they used to belong to some celebrity; but if you have "specialized glasses", they are not just ordinary "correct your vision" glasses but have some additional feature or capability that makes them useful in some narrower function; for example, they could be UV-resistant or heat-shielded.

*Worn* vs. *used* is more of a toss-up; if most of the gear being discussed is actually placed on your body and carried about like an article of clothing (and performs its protective function while doing so), then *worn* is fine.  If some significant portion must be carried around, then placed somewhere and set up before you use it, *used* could be more suitable.  Since the sentence talks specifically about "clothing or equipment", you could use both words: "...clothing or equipment that is worn or used by employees..."

*Security* vs. *safety* depends on the nature of the hazards that the gear is intended to protect against.  *Safety* is a broader range and is probably suitable for any protective gear; *Security* implies that the hazards being faced are due to hostile agents attempting to harm you.  (I would tend to think in terms of protection from gunshots/knives/blunt trauma for security, whereas safety could include protection from fire, slipping, acid, smoke inhalation, and any other environmental hazards.)